# Accessing Returned data from Controller

Tags: angularjs

I have data in a factory that I can view in the console.log from in the function, how can I get it into my controller?

It just comes back as undefined.

Factory

```
.factory('ThemeColor', function() {
    var db = new PouchDB('myDB');
    var self = {
      getColor: function(){
        db.get('themeColor').then(function(data){
          console.log(data);
          return data;
        });
      },
    }

    return self;
});
```

Controller

```
$scope.ThemeColor = function(){
  ThemeColor.getColor().then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
  };
```

Comment: what does console.log(data) return inside db.get('themeColor').then(function(data) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PouchDB` returns a `Promise`. Angular needs to know about the `Promise` when it resolves. As such, In your controller, use inject `$q` service and wrap the factory in `$q.when() as follows:

```
.factory('ThemeColor', function($q) {
var db = new PouchDB('myDB');
var self = {
  getColor: function(){
  return $q.when(db.get('themeColor')).then(function (data) {          
      return data;
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.error(err);
   });
  }
}

return self;
});
```

You can check out the docs

1. Angular documentation on [$q.when()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)
2. PouchDB note on Angular's [$q.when()](https://pouchdb.com/api.html) . Read the Section `Promises`

Comment: I've injected $q and am getting undefined from the console.log(data)

Comment: The console.log(data) in my controller is running before ThemeColor.getColor is run which is why it is comming back undefined therefore the promise is not working

Comment: I have updated the code. Edit as in the `factory ` and use your original `controller ` code

Comment: You may want to edit question and tag to reflect that it is a question related to Pouch DB and angular.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
$scope.ThemeColor = function(){
  $scope.color = null;
  ThemeColor.getColor().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $scope.color = data; // i am color
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not return a value from .then(function(data){}) since function(data){} is the callback.

You can use the below solution which will fulfill your need:

### Controller Code:

```
.controller('myCntrl', function($scope, ThemeColor) {
    function successCallback(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }

    function failureCallback(res) {
        // @TODO
    }


    $scope.ThemeColor = function(){
        ThemeColor.getColor(successCallback, failureCallback);
    };
});
```

### Service Code:

```
.factory('ThemeColor', function() {
    var db = new PouchDB('myDB');
    var self = {
      getColor: function(successCallback, failureCallback){
        db.get('themeColor').then(function(data){
            successCallback(data);
        }, function(data) {
            failureCallback(data);
        });
      }
    }

    return self;
});
```